# Usage of async/await in Mocha - test hangs or ends up with unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Running very simple test where I'm passing invalid credentials within the basic authorization header and I'm expecting the server to return 401

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const basicToken = require('basic-auth-token');

describe('PUT Endpoint', function () {
 it.only('should return unauthorized if basic token is incorrect', async function (done) {
                let options = {
                    url: `http://url_to_handle_request`,
                    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Basic ${basicToken('INVALID', 'CREDENTIALS')}`
                    }
                };

                try {
                    await request.put(options); // this should throw exception
                } catch (err) {
                    expect(err.statusCode).to.be.equal(401); // this is called
                }
                done();
            });
});
```

Problem with this code is that the `expect` clause resolves to false (because the server responded e.g. with 403) and the test ends up with error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected 403 to equal 401
```

If I omit the `done` callback, the test just hangs (the name is in red) and is apparently "waiting" for something to finish
[image]

I know it will work if I would rewrite it to use standard promises approach. I'm just curious how to do it via async/await.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `done` from parameter (and as well from function body), then Mocha will expect that you return Promise.

Async functions returns promises by default.

If you dont throw error, it returns resolved promise.

Comment: Thanks. Previously I had it implemented in this way but I couldn't see any difference. So I dived into the code and realized that it was the `after` function causing this.
So I've made corrections both to the async and the `after` and it started to work

Comment: If a promise rejection is not handled nor an error thrown it is called the 'falsey' state. Please read this post - https://ravichandranjv.blogspot.in/2018/03/the-unhandled-promise-rejection-state.html
- for a complete explanation on promises. An answer without supporting code is not really an answer. Please post supporting code for your answer,

Comment: @user2347763 - sorry, that is not correct. Throwing an error in async functon leads to returning rejected Promise, which leads to properly dismissed test with proper error message. When you dont put `done` variable inside test, it will expect returning promise (which async function always do) instead of calling callback.

Comment: @libik - please check out the blog post for a more elaborate explanation with code. If you are saying that done must be called because the async function supplied the callback then that is a different issue altogether. Your statement that "if you don't throw error it returns resolved promise" is not entirely correct because a promise has a falsy state when an empty promise is returned and your statement is actually the falsy state that you say is a resolved promise.

Comment: @user2347763 - sorry, that blog post is not related to the OP question and by itself does not say much and its quality is low. There is nothing like `falsey` state for mocha tests, you can have only resolved or rejected promise (if you omit the callback). Returning resolved empty promise (having null or undefined) is standard way for void functions.

Comment: @libik yes it is not. I just posted the link for you for you to refer to the screenshot of what messages are shown by nodejs. I cannot post the screenshot of a falsey state so will edit your post if it is ok with you. If not, you may simply reject the edit.

Comment: @user2347763 - please do not update other answers with your own opinions. The edit should be only used for some format changes or clear fixes (i.e. broken link...).

Comment: Yes, I have clearly mentioned the reason for the edit in my comment. It is in no way my opinion. Since you will not admit that a falsey state is actually a promise state despite the screenshot hat I put for your reference, I will update my answer with the screenshot for your reference. I would like you to respond ti how you claimed that there is nothing like false state for mocha tests when the nodejs message clearly states the state of the promise in the test result.

Answer (score -1):

Change this code block

```
try {
                    await request.put(options); // this should throw exception
                } catch (err) {
                    expect(err.statusCode).to.be.equal(401); // this is called
                }
                done();
```

to

```
                await request.put(options)
                    .then(()=>{ })
                    .catch(function (err)){ 
                      expect(err.statusCode).to.be.equal(401);
                     }
```

Comment: This really does not work properly, if error is thrown, the done is never called

Comment: @libik - do you even know what promises are and when done is called? For an unresolved promise rejection, the exception warning clearly says it will terminate the process so what do you mean done is never called if error is thrown? The .catch block helps handle the unresolved promise rejection.

Comment: You have .catch there, it means that it is not unresolved promise. If request.put throw error, it jump to catch (not using the then ->), use expect and if it pass, it will wait 2 secs and after it, it rejects it with timeout (or more seconds, if you set global timeout to different value)

Comment: If the test pass, ie., expect 403 and not 401, then the program (mocha) exits gracefully.

Comment: Actually not, sorry. If there is error, then `.then(() => done())` is not called. Lets say `expect(401)` is correct to expected `err.statusCode`, then this pass through and will be awaiting `done()`, which never be called and it ends with error - timeout

Comment: Well, yes, what you say is true but given the code, even done() in the .then block is not applicable because it is an over resolution. It should either be a callback or a promise, it cannot be both.

Comment: After this update and no other change, it will either fail with rejected promise error or timeout error. It never passes as done is never called.

Comment: There is a message from SO to avoid extended discussions in comments so will conclude the refute to your statement that calling done in a promise resolution is an over-specification.

Comment: `Falsey` is related only for rejected promises and only if you do something like "throw null", which could never happen in OP's example. I have never encoutered that in my life.

Comment: @libik - I am sure you know what promises are but just because you have not encountered a possibility, it doesn't mean it does not exist. Falsey is a state of a promise rejection that neither throws an error nor causes any failure, it is a simple, silent failure. Even in the OP's post, resolveWithFullResponse can easily fail silently with a half buffered or no response causing a silent failure of the request and it is not necessary that it should be a "throw null".

Comment: There is nothing like "Promise rejection that neither throws an error nor causes any failure". Promise is rejected or resolved -> nothing between. If rejected promise does not have proper Error inside, it can lead to some output problems as you expect object with `message` and `stack` inside.

Comment: Can you tell me who you are trying to influence with your comments? Because I have already shared the needed nodejs screenshot for a falsey state of a promise with you and your persistence is simply influencing negative responses to my comment. I would request you to accept that there is a falsey possibility of a promise and your answer to the OP is actually a falsey plus invalid because your answer suggests usage of both a falsey promise and a callback, which, node.js would respond with overspecification error, you can only use a callback or a promise.